# Solve equation like $f(x) = \log_2(g(x))$

Tags: logarithms

I've tried to solve two equations, and they look similar to me.
$$f(x) = \log_2(g(x))$$
In the original task, I should compare them, but I wanna solve them as equations. Is it possible using analytical method?
$$f(x) = \log_2(g(x))$$
Equations: $8n^2 = 64n\log_2(n)$ and $100n^2 = 2^n$
I'll give my thoughts with the first one.
$$8n^2 = 64n\log_2(n)$$
$$n = 8\log_2(n)$$
$$\log_2(2^n) = \log_2(n^8)$$
$$2^n = n^8$$
And now I'm stuck, does anybody have some suggestions?

Comment: Taking the $8$th root of both sides and rewriting gives $e^{n\ln(2)/8}=n$ (restricted to the positive root due to the original equation) from which one can apply the above. For the second one, taking the square root gives $\pm10n=e^{n\ln(2)/2}$.

Comment: If the desire is for numerical solutions, I would suggest fixed-point iteration, Newton's method, or bisection, as simple starting points.

Comment: Yep, forgot that @SimplyBeautifulArt

Comment: You have $n2^{-n/8}=1$ or $-\frac{n\ln 2}{8}e^{-n\ln 2/8}=-\frac{\ln 2}{8}$ or $-\frac{n\ln 2}{8}=-\frac{n\ln 2}{8}=W\left(-\frac{\ln 2}{8}\right)$ or $$n = -\frac{8}{\ln 2}W\left(-\frac{\ln 2}{8}\right)$$ where $W$ is the Lambert $W$-function.

Comment: Thank you, all. I appreciate your help. But for now, I don't know what "Lambert W-function" is :D Guess it's to complex for me now :C

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, if u write it as an answer, I'll mark it :D (voted for all ur comments instead :D)

Comment: @Kamushek I can't, the question is closed.

Comment: Google Lambert $W$ function. $W(z)$ is the solution of $we^w=z.$

Comment: In particular, if $-1/e<z<0$ there are two real values of $w.$ Since $-1/e<-\frac{\ln 2}{8}<0$ there are two values of $n.$ We see that there is a solution between $1$ and $2.$ and another solution between $32$ and $64.$

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t an analytical method but you could find particular integer solutions and study the associated real valued function to know number of solutions.

For example if you’re looking for solutions of $n^8=2^n$, you can see that $n^8$ and so $n$ must be a power of $2$. So suppose $n=2^a$, we want $2^{8a}=2^{2^a}\iff 8a=2^a\iff 2^{a-3}=a$ but by induction you can see that for all $a\ge 6$ then $2^{a-3}>a$ and for $a<6$ by inspection you see there aren’t solution.

If you wanted the solutions of, for instance $2^n=n^2$ you could see that $n=2$ and $n=4$ are solutions, to show they are unique you must recur to calculus: calling $f(x)=2^x-x^2$ we see that $f’(x)=2^x\ln 2-2x$ and $f’’(x)=2^x\cdot \ln^2 2-2>0$ for $x\ge 3$, so in $[3,\infty) $ we could have at most one solution, that is $x=4$.

Comment: There is an analytic solution, if you allow the Lambert $W$-function.

Comment: Does it allows us to do an analytical algorithm to show exact solutions?

Comment: I've tried to find smth to Thomas's solution, but ur's is good c: